# Перечисляемый тип данных в C

Tags: c, указатели, enum

Цель состоит в том, чтобы написать ф-ции к структуре "Сгибы". Это своего рода то, как мы можем согнуть лист, у нас есть "вмятина" и "выпухлости".

```
typedef enum {creux, bosse} Pli;
```

Последовательность сгибов :

```
typedef Pli *suite;
```

Пустая последовательность :

```
suite suite_vide() {
    suite s = (Pli*)malloc(sizeof(Pli));
    *s = fin;
    return s;
}
```

Здесь fin это конец нашей последовательности

```
#define fin '\0'
```

Длина последовательности :

```
 int longueur(suite s) {
int i = 0;
while (*s != fin) {
    i++; s++;
}
return i;}
```

добавление сгиба в последовательность сгибов   :

```
 suite ajout_fin(suite s, Pli p) {
    suite sp = (Pli*)malloc((longueur(s)+2)*sizeof(Pli));
    suite parc = sp;
    for ( ; *s != fin; s++, parc++)
        *parc = *s;
    *parc++ = p;
    *parc = fin;
    return sp;
}
```

Вывод на экран последовательности :

```
    void affiche_suite(suite s) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < longueur(s); i++) {
        printf("%d :  %d\n",i,s[i]);
    }
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что полностью игнорируются creux, когда я хочу добавить его в свою последовательность ( если поменять местами с bosse, то тогда bosse будет игнорироваться)
Пример теста :

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv){
            suite s = suite_vide();
            s = ajout_fin(ajout_fin(ajout_fin(s,creux),bosse),creux);
            printf("long : %d\n",longueur(s));
            affiche_suite(s);
            return 0;
        }
```

Результат :

```
long : 1
0 :  1
```

Еще пример теста :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    suite s = suite_vide();
    s = ajout_fin(ajout_fin(ajout_fin(s, bosse),bosse),bosse);
    printf("long : %d\n",longueur(s));
    affiche_suite(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Результат :

```
long : 3
    0 :  1
    1 :  1
    2 :  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что если значения констант входящих в `enum` не заданы явно, то они номеруются по порядку начиная с нуля таким образом числовым значением `creux` является `0`, что совпадает с признаком конца последовательности `fin`. Само собой каждый `creux` интерпретируется как конец последовательности.
Из вариантов решения:

- Можно явно задать значения констант в enum

  ```
  typedef enum {creux = 'c', bosse = 'b'} Pli;
  ```
- Можно включить `fin` в свой `enum`

  ```
  typedef enum {fin, creux, bosse} Pli;
  ```

Из остальных замечаний:

- Здесь с большой вероятностью длина будет пересчитываться на каждой итерации:

  > ```
  > for (i = 0; i < longueur(s); i++) {
  > ```
- В данном случае будет намного проще, эффективней и поятней иметь простой массив `char` и работать с последовательностью как со строкой, если именно не в работе с `enum`'ом или в избыточной инкапсуляции состоит суть задачи.